# Show that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(kx) \, dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm working through some old test problems in preparation for a Real Analysis exam. I got stuck on the following problem:

> Show that if $f$ is (Lebesgue) integrable on $[0,1]$, then $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(kx) \, dx = 0$$

It seems to me that the idea is to move the limit inside the integral. I know that $f(x)\sin(kx)$ is bounded by $f(x)$ which is integrable, so I thought maybe the bounded or dominated convergence theorems might be useful. However, I don't have a sequence of integrable functions converging point-wise to $0$. How can I proceed, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Apply the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Hint: use simple function to approximate $f(x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh yeah that seems quite applicable indeed! This is just the limit of the imaginary component of $\int_0^1 f(x) e^{ikx} dx$. So since the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma gives $\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x) e^{ikx} dx = 0$, the limit of the imaginary component must also go to zero. Is it really that simple?

Comment: @M47145 Yes, it is that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

If $f$ is has a continuous derivative and $f(1)=0$ then integration by parts yields
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(kx) \,dx = f(1)(\sin k) - \int_0^1 f'(x) \frac 1 k \sin(kx) \, dx = \frac 1 k\int_0^1 f'(x) \sin(kx)\,dx
$$
And taking absolute values on both sides and showing that the last expression goes to $0$ (since $|f'(x)\sin(kx)| \le \max\{ |f'(x)| : 0\le x\le 1\}$) will do it.

But what if $f(1)\ne0$ or $f$ does not have a continuous derivative? The linked Wikipedia article says one can approximate $f$ in $L^1$ with another function $g$ that has those propoerties.